# Voting redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I downloaded the PHP voting script from this website:

I have installed this and it works perfectly on my website, however I am looking at customising it slightly so that once a user has voted it then redirects them to a new page, or ideally opens up a lightbox.

I have narrowed it down to a javascript problem, and the javascript file is within the voting.js file.

Below is the following code found in that file:

```
// Ajax Voting Script - http://www.coursesweb.net
var ivotings = Array();         // store the items with voting
var ar_elm = Array();       // store the items that will be send to votAjax()
var i_elm = 0;                  // Index for elements aded in ar_elm
var itemvotin = '';       // store the voting of voted item
var votingfiles = 'votingfiles/';      // directory with files for script
var advote = 0;      // variable checked in addVote(), if is 0 cann vote, else, not

// gets all DIVs, store in $ivotings, and in $ar_elm DIVs with class: "vot_plus", "vot_updown", and ID="vt_..", sends to votAjax()
var getVotsElm = function () {
  var obj_div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var nrobj_div = obj_div.length;
  for(var i=0; i<nrobj_div; i++) {
    // if contains class and id
    if(obj_div[i].className && obj_div[i].id) {
        var elm_id = obj_div[i].id;
      // if class "vot_plus", "vot_updown1", "vot_updown2", or "vot_poll" and id begins with "vt_"
      if((obj_div[i].className=='vot_plus' || obj_div[i].className=='vot_updown1' || obj_div[i].className=='vot_updown2') && elm_id.indexOf("vt_")==0) {
        ivotings[elm_id] = obj_div[i];       // store object item in $ivotings

        ar_elm[i_elm] = elm_id;     // add item_ID in $ar_elm array, to be send in json string tp php
        i_elm++;             // index order in $ar_elm
      }
    }
  }
  // if there are elements in "ar_elm", send them to votAjax()
  if(ar_elm.length>0) votAjax(ar_elm, '');      // if items in $ar_elm pass them to votAjax()
};

// add the ratting data to element in page
function addVotData(elm_id, vote, nvotes, renot) {
  // exists elm_id stored in ivotings
  if(ivotings[elm_id]) {
    // sets to add "onclick" for vote up (plus), if renot is 0
    var clik_up = (renot == 0) ? ' onclick="addVote(this, 1)"' : ' onclick="alert(\'You already voted\')"';

    // if vot_plus, add code with <img> 'votplus', else, if vot_updown1/2, add code with <img> 'votup',  'votdown'
    if(ivotings[elm_id].className == 'vot_plus') {    // simple vote
      ivotings[elm_id].innerHTML = '<h4>'+ vote+ '</h4><span><img src="'+votingfiles+'votplus.gif" alt="1" title="Vote"'+ clik_up+ '/></span>';
    }
    else if(ivotings[elm_id].className=='vot_updown1') {   // up/down with total Votes
      // sets to add "onclick" for vote down (minus), if renot is 0
      var clik_down = (renot == 0) ? ' onclick="addVote(this, -1)"' : ' onclick="alert(\'You already voted\')"';

      ivotings[elm_id].innerHTML = '<div id="nvotes">Votes: <b>'+ nvotes+ '</b></div><h4>'+ vote+ '</h4><span><img src="'+votingfiles+'votup.png" alt="Vote Up" title="Vote Up"'+ clik_up+ '/> <img src="'+votingfiles+'votdown.png" alt="Vote Down" title="Vote Down"'+ clik_down+ '/></span>';
    }
    else if(ivotings[elm_id].className=='vot_updown2') {      // up/down with number of votes up and down
      var nvup = (nvotes*1 + vote*1) /2;       // number of votes up
      var nvdown = nvotes - nvup;              // number of votes down

      // sets to add "onclick" for vote down (minus), if renot is 0
      var clik_down = (renot == 0) ? ' onclick="addVote(this, -1)"' : ' onclick="alert(\'You already voted\')"';

      ivotings[elm_id].innerHTML = '<h4>'+ vote+ '</h4><span><img src="'+votingfiles+'votup.png" alt="Vote Up" title="Vote Up"'+ clik_up+ '/> <img src="'+votingfiles+'votdown.png" alt="Vote Down" title="Vote Down"'+ clik_down+ '/></span><div id="nupdown"><b id="nvup">'+ nvup+ '</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; <b id="nvdown">'+ nvdown+ '</b></div>';
    }
  }
}

// Sends data to votAjax(), that will be send to PHP to register the vote
function addVote(ivot, vote) {
  // if $advote is 0, can vote, else, alert message
  if(advote == 0) {
    var elm = Array();
    elm[0] = ivot.parentNode.parentNode.id;      // gets the item-name that will be voted

    ivot.parentNode.innerHTML = '<i><b>Thanks</b></i>';
    votAjax(elm, vote);
  }
  else alert('You already voted');
}

/*** Ajax ***/

// create the XMLHttpRequest object, according to browser
function get_XmlHttp() {
  var xmlHttp = null;           // will stere and return the XMLHttpRequest

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     // Forefox, Opera, Safari, ...
  else if(window.ActiveXObject) xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");     // IE

  return xmlHttp;
}

// sends data to PHP and receives the response
function votAjax(elm, vote) {
  var cerere_http =  get_XmlHttp();     // get XMLHttpRequest object

  // define data to be send via POST to PHP (Array with name=value pairs)
  var datasend = Array();
  for(var i=0; i<elm.length; i++) datasend[i] = 'elm[]='+elm[i];
  // joins the array items into a string, separated by '&'
  datasend = datasend.join('&')+'&vote='+vote;

  cerere_http.open("POST", votingfiles+'voting.php', true);         // crate the request

  cerere_http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    // header for POST
  cerere_http.send(datasend);       //  make the ajax request, poassing the data

  // checks and receives the response
  cerere_http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (cerere_http.readyState == 4) {
      // receives a JSON with one or more item:[vote, nvotes, renot]
      eval("var jsonitems = "+ cerere_http.responseText);

      // if jsonitems is defined variable
      if (jsonitems) {
        // parse the jsonitems object
        for(var votitem in jsonitems) {
          var renot = jsonitems[votitem][2];        // determine if the user can vote or not

          // if renot=3 displays alert that already voted, else, continue with the voting reactualization
           if(renot == 3) {
            alert("You already voted \n You can vote again tomorrow");
            window.location.reload(true);       // Reload the page
          }
          else addVotData(votitem, jsonitems[votitem][0], jsonitems[votitem][1], renot);    // calls function that shows voting
        }
      }

      // if renot is undefined or 2 (set to 1 NRVOT in voting.php), after vote, set $advote to 1
      if(vote != '' && (renot == undefined || renot == 2)) advote = 1;
      }
  }
}

// this function is used to access the function we need after loading page
function addLoadVote(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload; 

  // if the parameter is a function, calls it with "onload"
  // otherwise, adds the parameter into a function, and then call it
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') window.onload = func;
  else { 
    window.onload = function() { 
      if (oldonload) { oldonload(); } 
      func();
    } 
  } 
}

addLoadVote(getVotsElm);            // calls getVotsElm() after page loads
```

I did have a go at doing this myself and it did work in certain browsers, but not others.  All I did was add change the code on line 66 from:

ivot.parentNode.innerHTML = '***Thanks***';

to:

ivot.parentNode = window.location = "register2.php";

But as I said, this only works on certain browsers as on other browsers it doesn't add the information to the database, anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax request and the database operations are executed in the `votAjax(elm, vote)`. So you have to add the code for redirecting after the execution of that request.

Most likely between lines 100-115

Comment: What code is best using after this? is it best to use the following code:

window.top.location = 'register2.php';

Any example code you can provide to paste in that area?

Comment: window.location.href = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/register.php'.       I think this will do the trick

Comment: Thanks for that, what line do you think that should go on?

Comment: It should go to line 115 in the else condition.   else addVotData(votitem, jsonitems[votitem][0], jsonitems[votitem][1], renot);    should be replaced with else window.location.href = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/register.php'.

Comment: I tried replacing what was there with the new code, but it just redirects the page when you load the voting script, any ideas?

Comment: That needs some detailed checking... is the code hosted in any public domains where i can check it?

Comment: This is because the same code is called in the document load also.

Comment: i have tweaked the code a bit.. try this    `if(vote == '' || vote == null) //for document onLoad condtion
    addVotData(votitem, jsonitems[votitem][0], jsonitems[votitem][1], renot);    // calls function that shows voting
    else
    window.location.href = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/register.php'`

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure where each bit goes, could you possibly split this out, or possibly send me the whole script with amends?

Comment: there is a function `votAjax(...)` in the code. In that function replace `else addVotData(...);` with  `else{ //the code given above}`

Comment: Great, that works a treat thanks so much for your help.

One final thing, are you able to make this open within the fancy box script instead of redirecting the page? (You can see the fancy box script working when you click the upload tab).

Any ideas?

Comment: try this   `$.fancybox.open({
    href: window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/register.php,
    type: 'iframe'
});`

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for your help on this, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean :

```
window.top.location = 'register2.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I have tried that code instead and it is still causing the issues.

I think the issues lies with that it takes you away from the page before it adds the vote to the database.  I think this code just needs adding below somewhere, but not quite sure where, any ideas?

Comment: this code of course adds in ajax onSuccess / onComplete event

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, what do you mean? any possible code snippets or areas where to add the code?

Comment: add the line near `if (cerere_http.readyState == 4) {`, at the last line before closing the `if`. On the other hand, you should use AJAX framework instead of writing so many codes for AJAX. try jQuery.